# How to write properties file in Groovy without escape characters and single quotes?

Tags: groovy, escaping

I have something like:

```
def newProps = new Properties()
def fileWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(propsFile,true), 'UTF-8')
def lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator")

newProps.setProperty('SFTP_USER_HASH', userSftpHome.toString())
newProps.setProperty('GD_SFTP_URI', sftpHost.toString())

fileWriter.write(lineSeparator)
newProps.store(fileWriter, null)
fileWriter.close()
```

The problem is that store() method escapes **":"** or **"="** characters with backslash (). I don't want that because I store there some passwords and tokens and need to copy those values strictly in the key=value format.

Also, when I use the configSlurper, it stores the values with single quotes, like:

```
key='value'
```

Is there any solution for that? Saving in unescaped key=value format to properties file in Groovy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this:

```
def newProps = new Properties()
newProps.setProperty('SFTP_USER_HASH', 'woo')
newProps.setProperty('GD_SFTP_URI', 'ftp://woo.com')

propsFile.withWriterAppend( 'UTF-8' ) { fileWriter ->
    fileWriter.writeLine ''
    newProps.each { key, value ->
        fileWriter.writeLine "$key=$value"
    }
}
```

BUT, so long as you are reading the properties in with `load`, there should be no need for this as it should de-escape any escaped characters

Answer (score 1):

The JDK's built in `Properties` class does that escaping by design. According to the [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String%29):

> Then every entry in this Properties table is written out, one per
>   line. For each entry the key string is written, then an ASCII =, then
>   the associated element string. For the key, all space characters are
>   written with a preceding \ character. For the element, leading space
>   characters, but not embedded or trailing space characters, are written
>   with a preceding \ character. The key and element characters #, !, =,
>   and : are written with a preceding backslash to ensure that they are
>   properly loaded.

You can however, override this behavior by sub-classing the `Properties` class yourself. You'd need to override the `load` and `store` methods yourself and read/write yourself. It would be pretty straight forward; pretty good examples found here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8238984/772385)