# Not able to read Properties File using Backward Slash

Tags: java, string, properties

I Am not able to read Properties File using Java.It Means In this Properties File Backward Slash is not working.It is showing like ,this destination :C:Usersxxx.a

```
String filename="D://Desktop//xxx.properties";
is = new FileInputStream(filename);
Properties prop=new Properties();
prop.load(is);
System.out.println("destination :"+prop.getProperty("destination"));
```

Property File is the :

```
destination=C:\Users\xxx.a\
```

Result is showing

```
destination :C:Usersxxx.a
```

But I want to show  destination :C:\Usersxxx.a\

Can You Please suggest Me?

Comment: can you change property file?

Comment: No i can't change Properties File..

Comment: you can read file as textfile or read accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233532/reading-java-properties-file-without-escaping-values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Properties backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784895/java-properties-backslash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\` is an Escape character.

forward slash `/` is used as path separator in Unix environment.
Back slash `\` is used as path separator in Windows environment.
So, You need to use `\\` or `/` as path separator. You can not directly use `\` in java. Since, it is an escape character.

So,You need to make changes in your properties file to make your program work.
Use either `/` or `\\` as path separator in your properties file.

In your case you want to show as `C:\Users\xxx.a\`.
So, use `C:\\Users\\xxx.a\\` in your properties file to get output as `C:\Users\xxx.a\`

Comment: No i dont want  to add double slash ,if i add it will show in result as C:\Users\xxx.a\ .Is there  any other way programatically?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two slashes to your properties file like this:
`destination=C:\\Users\\xxx.a\\`

The other way is to swap the slashes in the properties file:
`destination=C:/Users/xxx.a/`

A `\` is an escape character so it is removed. Adding two slashes escapes the first so only one is left.

Comment: Thank For Reply...But I need to add only C:\Users\xxx.a\  If we add double slash It ll work...

Comment: If you add two slashes to your properties file it will only show one slash for your destination. With just one slash in the properties file it is getting escaped so nothing is showed. Having two slashes in the properties file means the first is escaped and the second will be used, hence only one appears.

Comment: If we add 2 slash in properties ,it ll show in destinition single.yeah itz fine.but i dont  want to add double slash in properties file

Answer (score 0):

The `\` character is used as an "escape character" in many programming languages. It gives a special meaning to the next character in the text. For example, `\n` encodes the special character "new-line".

Use `\\` instead of `\`. This indicates to the parser that you mean the actual symbol, not an escape character. For example, your property value would be:

```
destination=C:\\Users\\xxx.a\\
```

Comment: I need to add only sing slash in Properties File.If we add double slash..it is working..

Comment: @mdrazi The \\ is interpreted as a single backslash character in your actual property. Your final property value will contain only one `\' between each directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in D:/Desktop/xxx.properties as

```
destination=C:/Users/xxx.a/
```

and show it with a single backslash

```
String fileName = prop.getProperty("destination");
System.out.println("destination: " + fileName); // shows: C:/Users/xxx.a/
System.out.println("destination: " + Paths.get(fileName)); // shows: C:\Users\xxx.a
```