# Linux File path- escape characters for Java Application?

Tags: java, linux, properties, escaping, filepath

In my Java Application I have a properties Class (shown below). This class refers to application.properties file on the Linux Server.

What is the correct form to enter the file path, do I need Escape Chars?

Current Properties class:

```
**
 * Properties class used to obtain properties from the
 * application.properties file
 */
public class MyProperties {

    private static Properties props = new Properties();
    static {
        try {
           //path to file on server
            java.io.InputStream in= new FileInputStream("/path/to/file/application.properties");
            props.load(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a given property by its key
     * @param key
     * @return
     */
    public static String getProperty(String key) {

        return props.getProperty(key);
    }

}
```

Should I be using: `//path//to//file//application.properties` rather than my current implementation?

Answer (score -1):

If you use single quote, you don't need to escape anything.
it will escape everything needs to be escaped in shell mode.

Try to use:

```
java.io.InputStream in= new FileInputStream('/path/to/file/application.properties');
```

According to your comment, I add this link referring to properties files:

[Reading Java Properties file without escaping values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233532/reading-java-properties-file-without-escaping-values)

Maybe it full fit what you need

Comment: Ok, and on the properties file on the box, do I need to add any quotes at all, or just specify the path?

Comment: Please, see the link.
It was added to the answer for clarity.

Comment: I tried to use Single Quotes, but got the error: "Too many characters in String Literal" ?