# How to replaces white spaces from String loaded through properties

Tags: java, properties, path, removing-whitespace

I am loading property from file, the property contains path (Windows path) and I need to normalize it to create usable path. The problem is that I can't replace "\".

Here is my test class:

```
public class PathUtil {

    public static String normalizeEscapeChars(String source) {
        String result = source;

        result = result.replace("\b", "/b");
        result = result.replace("\f", "/f");
        result = result.replace("\n", "/n");
        result = result.replace("\r", "/r");
        result = result.replace("\t", "/t");
        result = result.replace("\\", "/");
        result = result.replace("\"", "/\"");
        result = result.replace("\'", "/'");
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try(FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Rakieta\\Desktop\\aaa.properties")) {
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(input);
            System.out.println(PathUtil.normalizeEscapeChars(prop.getProperty("aaa")));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here property file:

```
aaa=Intermix\koza , intermix\trace
```

Actual output is :

```
Intermixkoza , intermix/trace
```

Needed output is :

```
Intermix/koza , intermix/trace
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backslash is already interpreted by the `java.util.Properties` class.

To bypass this, you can extend it and tweak the `load(InputStream)` method as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6321416/7525132):

```
public class PropertiesEx extends Properties {
    public void load(FileInputStream fis) throws IOException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(fis);
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        while(in.hasNext()) {
            out.write(in.nextLine().replace("\\","\\\\").getBytes());
            out.write("\n".getBytes());
        }

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
        super.load(is);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I copied your code my IDE threw an error saying `\k` is not a valid escape character. So I removed the whole line.

```
result = result.replace("\k", "/k");
// I have not seen that escape character (Correct me if I am wrong)
```

And my output was

> aaa=Intermix/koza , intermix/trace

or you try what Connor said that is

```
result = result.replace("\\k", "/k");
// This code is replacing \k with /k in Intermix\koza. So it is kinda hard coded.
```

which also gives the same result.

Comment: Updated srr i left that "\k" and forgot to delete before upload. The problem is that i cant limit it to just "k" it has to work for any char. Double \ is not working it cannot convert "\" form file automatically to "\\".

Comment: And btw how you got output of whole property file?  when you are reading only the value of property?

Answer (score 0):

Use double backslash `\\` to escape a backslash in java.

Comment: I know that, but that property file gonna be customizable by client and I don’t want to force them to to think about it